# Sending numpy array over socket and retrieving it in java

Tags: java, python, numpy, sockets

Basically I want to send the output of Decision tree classifier over socket and get the output in java. I want to predict disease from symptoms. I'll send my sample test vector of symptoms from java through socket and want to get the predicted disease from python.

```
`dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf_dt=dt.fit(x,y)
output=clf_dt.predict(sym)
print(output) #prints ['Fungal infection']`
```

Now I want to send this "Fungal infection" through socket and get it in java.

```
`data_string = pickle.dumps(output)
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) 
s.bind(("localhost",9000)) 
s.listen(10)
connection, address = s.accept()
message             = connection.recv(1024)
print ("Got: {0}".format(message))
connection.send(data_string) #PROBLEM is here.I can't retrieve this in 
java
connection.close()`
```

Thanks...

Comment: A `pickle` string is a Python specific format.  It's unlikely that you'll be able to use it in Java, though might be able to store it, and send it back to Python for reading with `pickle`.  Otherwise you'll need to define a format that is usable on both sides.

Comment: I actually wanted to convert it into string. But tostring() is also not working. When I used conn.send(str.encode(output.tostring())) it also didn't work saying 'str' object is reqd. but it's getting 'bytes'

Comment: Yes, if you check the docs, `tostring` produces a bytestring.  It may help if you gave a clear example of what the array should look like at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself. tostring() is returning bytes. np.array2string(x) returned me a str object which I can pass through socket